# Cleanning Project deletes R.java files

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

My project works fine without any error until i clean it . When i clean my project deletes all R.java files in and doensn't recreate them. I looked lots of posts but i couldnt solve my problem.

> My drawebles seems fine.
>
> I also tried to check my layout files but i couldn't see anything wrong with them.

As i said it works fine until clean. I can run it or debug it.Also when i started my project it gives lint error.Is there any solid solution for this situation.

Comment: That is normal AFAIK. `R.java` is generated at compilation time... So a clean removes it. A rebuild/build re-generates it. What was your problem?

Comment: Build automatically is already selected. But even building manually doesnt recreate them.

Comment: So you got an error? Again, what is the problem? Because, again, "cleaning project deletes R.java file" is not a problem, it is a normal and expected behavior...

Comment: Fix the lint error and your application will compile (and generate the R.java file) normally again.

Comment: i have no idea why its giving lint error. It just says lint error and NullPointerException as detail

Comment: Can you post the full lint error message and/or Exception stacktrace?

Comment: lint error was just NullPointerExeption. I solved this with  just openning a new project and copying all files in it. Now it seems fine. But i still dont know why its happened and why it ve solved !

Answer (score 0):

Lint error usually occurs when you have more than one eclipse running on your computer. And about R.java  error, restart eclipse/check your android manifest file, sometimes you may find some problem in your manifest. It is yet not clear why the clean removes R.java. Even check for Properties of the project in Android and Java Build Path options, to see if appropriate options are ticked! Hope you get success! Thanks..

Comment: they are seem fine. Also as i said without cleanning i can run my project.

Comment: @BahadirGul, Yes you are right. But you need to clean your projects. And if the error still continues, double check all your xml files, change your project location, restart eclipse and see. This is what i did when i faced the same problem. I had some errors in my XML files. Thanks!!

Comment: @Shuruti thanks for your response. Currently i dont have any errors but i will double check all of my xml files again.